# When I use Response.Redirect() or Server.Transfer() my user gets logged out

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using #4 on [this tutorial](http://forums.asp.net/t/1403132.aspx) to do authentication.

If I login, and then manually navigate to the page I need I do not get logged out. However, if I use `Response.Redirect()` or `Server.Transfer()` my user is instantly logged out.

Here is my code

```
protected void  Login1_Authenticate(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    string userName = Login1.UserName;
    string password = Login1.Password;

    bool result = UserLogin(userName, password); // This method executes SQL on my own database and returns true if the username and password work
    if ((result))
    {
        e.Authenticated = true;

        // Redirect users to some page
        Response.Redirect("/home.aspx"); // THIS CAUSES A LOGOUT
    }
    else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow, please post some relevant code. We have no way of just guessing what the problem might be.

Comment: I have added relevant code.

Comment: Does it login properly if you remove the response.redirect code? I dont see anywhere where you actually start a session or use an form of actually authenticating the user. Ex: FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, persist);?

Comment: I am new with ASP.NET does e.authenticated = true; not set any of this for me? How would I manually set my session up? I assumed the tutorial I referenced above covered the angles I needed

Comment: Also yes if Response.Redirect() gets removed everything works like a charm. I can even navigate manually to my page and it all works as expected. I am even able to use <%: User.Identity.Name %> on other pages as if everything was working properly.

Comment: E.Authenticated = true just tells the login control that you have successfully logged the user in so it does not show any errors.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240 - look at that url as to how to use formsauthentication. Response.Redirect can be dangerous because it can end the processing of the request and certain things such as events native to asp.net might never get called.

Comment: I assume I need this "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);" will "FormsAuthentication.SignOut();" destroy that for me?

Comment: Yes it will destroy the auth cookie and log the user out. There are other methods on on formsauthentication for changing urls and other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) immediately cancels all remaining code in the current page flow so the code that would normally use the Authenticated flag to indicate the user is authenticated is never executed.

If you are using the Login control, you can use the [DestinationPageURL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.destinationpageurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property in the control to automatically redirect to the Home.aspx page.

Comment: What about "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);"? Is that being done for me when I am using the above method minus the Response.Redirect()?

Comment: I just tested your solution, my user still gets logged out unless I do FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);

Comment: @user3108526: I just looked at the tutorial you are using and it definitely appears like you will need to use SetAuthCookie to authenticate the user. We have never used the Login control, choosing instead to handle all of the work directly since we have our own user storage. We found that we had much more control and understanding of the program flow this way.

Comment: That makes sense. Can you send me some materials on how you handle your own directly?

Comment: @user3108526: We created a login screen with our own user name, password, and login buttons. On login, we validate the user credentials against our database and, if valid, we just call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie with the user key as the first parameter and false as the second. Our web.config has the following entry in the authentication block: <forms name=".AUTH" loginUrl="default.aspx?reauth=1" protection="All" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60" />. Has been working like a charm for about 10 years now.

Comment: Persistent cookies mean if they close the browser it stays, wouldnt it be more secure to have that off? I figure some users like that by closing the browser their session is killed.

Comment: Setting the second parameter to false ensures that the cookie is NOT  persistent, which is definitely what we want in this case.